# jQuery event not working on correct element

Tags: jquery, events, keypress

I am putting full code here so that there is nothing missed which could cause this issue to happen.

Following steps to replicate the issue after running the code.

1. Click on +, it will create a new unordered list `ul` with an `li`.
2. Click inside `li` and type something and press `Enter`. It will create a new `li` after it. So there is a `keypress` event bound on each `li` which on Enter inserts a new `li` after it.
3. Now type something in second `li` and press Tab. It will put this `li` inside previous `li`. A tab press event is also bound.
4. Now again click on same `li` and press Enter. Here the problem is occurring.

It is expected the new `li` will be inserted just after this but actually it is getting inserted after the parent `li`.

After debugging it shows that $(this) is referring to parent `li`, inside code handled for `keypress` event.

Please let me know why this is happening.

```js
   $('document').ready(function() {
      $('#plus').click(function() {
        $('#notes').append(fillnote());
      });
    });

    function fillnote() {
      var $ul = $('<ul>').addClass('myUL').append(getLi());
      var node = $('<div>').append($ul);
      return node;
    }

    function getLi()
    {
      return $('<li>').addClass('edit-list')
      .attr('contentEditable', true);
    }
    
    $(document).on('keydown', '.edit-list', function(e) {
      var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

      //Enter key
      if (keyCode == 13) {
        var $newLi = getLi();
        $(this).after($newLi);
        $newLi.focus();
        return false;
      }
      //Tab Key
      if (keyCode == 9) {
          console.log(this);
          moveInsidePrevSibling($(this));
          return false;
      }
    });

    function moveInsidePrevSibling($obj)
    {
      var $prev = $obj.prev();
      var $ul = $('<ul>').addClass('myUL');
        $prev.append($ul);
      $ul.append($obj);
    }
```

```css
#notes
{
 min-height: 800px;
 width:800px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 8px 5px 20px;
    background: #eee;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: auto;

}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

ul li:hover {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <span id="plus">+</span>
    <div id="notes"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think this will be very difficult, because of how event delegation works since your child element is inside your parent which has an event listener for `keydown` as well, `$(this)` will always be the parent I think. I would suggest separating the two event functionality with unique reference class or ids.

Comment: This process is nested. So I cannot use ids and separate classname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to figure out the issue and it has nothing to do with jquery.

It turns out that culprit is `contentEditable` attribute. I set this attribute to true for all `li's`. There is a bug that when child and parent both have this attribute as `true`, any `keypress` event applies to parent instead of child.

I confirmed this by setting attribute for parent as `false` and it worked.